# What is pigpiod's analogon to the ADS1x1x_i2c_start_read () procedure in ADS1115's driver?

Tags: i2c, pigpio

To make an ADS1115 ADC module running on my Raspi 3B, I am trying to use the [driver supplied by Elektor Labs](https://github.com/ElektorLabs/ads1115-driver). The driver requires the user to develop the low-level part (I²C commands) himself and then to attach it to the backend API of the driver, which consists of [these procedures](https://github.com/ElektorLabs/ads1115-driver/blob/master/ads1x1x.h#L27):

```c
// I2C stubs, implementations to be provided by the user.
extern uint8_t ADS1x1x_i2c_start_write(uint8_t i2c_address);
extern uint8_t ADS1x1x_i2c_write(uint8_t x);
extern uint8_t ADS1x1x_i2c_start_read(uint8_t i2c_address, uint16_t bytes_to_read);
extern uint8_t ADS1x1x_i2c_read(void);
extern uint8_t ADS1x1x_i2c_stop(void);
```

I am using the [I²C API of `pigpiod`](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html#i2c_open). Now, here is my question: Which `pigpiod` function(s) are necessary to implement the `ADS1x1x_i2c_start_read ()` function?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a 1 to 1 mapping.

You need to get a handle to the I2C device at the start of your program using [i2c_open](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html#i2c_open).

At the end of your program release the handle with [i2c_close](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html#i2c_close).

To write one or more bytes use [i2c_write_device](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html#i2c_write_device).

To read one or more bytes use [i2c_read_device](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html#i2c_read_device).

Comment: Not i2c_write_byte resp. i2c_read_byte?

Comment: @Neppomuk You can use those if you want to read/write just one byte.  Whatever works for your situation.

Comment: As the function signatures prescribe `uint8_t` as return value, I strongly suppose that they shall work one byte only with every call.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out, I found out that there is **no analogon** at all between the pigpiod routines, and the low-level procedures required by the ADS1115 driver: `ADS1x1x_i2c_start_write ()`, for instance, is expected to send a start bit and a write bit to the ADC and nothing more. On the other hand, `ADS1x1x_i2c_stop ()` shall send a stop bit and nothing else.

Unfortunately, this is not documented in the source code, nor in the readme file.